# txt to csv attempt. cannot understand the TypeError from re

Tags: python, csv, python-re, txt

I am trying to convert this file https://bpa.st/SNPQ into a CSV file. I have spent a long time putting this code together but I don't understand why it is failing.

```
import re
f = open('PRM93052012100845','r')
text = f.readlines()
text = re.sub('^\n|\n$','',text)
for no,line in enumerate(text.splitlines()):
    print('"'+'","'.join([i.replace('"','\\"').strip() for i in re.split('(?<=^[0-9]{2})([0-9]{13}| {13})|  +',text.splitlines()[no].strip()) if i != None])+'"')
```

(there many more lines than what is in the paste sample)

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ben/Documents/WDL Content/eCom Python/printtest.py", line 5, in <module>
    text = re.sub('^\n|\n$','',text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 210, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I wish I could say there is some erroneous data within the file but there is an MS Office Macro that completing the same objective. I would love to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `f.readlines()` returns a list, use `read()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text = f.readlines()` gives you list, hence you cannot use  it with `re.sub` as it expects `string` or `bytes`. replace it with `text = f.read()`

Comment: thank you, this seems to have resolved it!

Comment: glad it helped :), you can mark it accepted if solves your issue